# Nodejs telnet live response fetching

Tags: node.js, telnet

I am using Nodejs with Express. Is there any way to get all the response content from a request at the same time. I am using telnet to make the request, but am not getting all content at the same time. Instead, I am getting it part by part. I need to extract data from that response so I am trying to write all the contents to a file and then convert that xml file content to json.

Comment: You should provide your example code and data. As it is, it is not very clear what you mean by "continuously part by part" . Also, Express is a HTTP web server. Telnet is a protocol different from HTTP.

Comment: Corrected grammar errors and reworded for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you use streams for that purposes.
So, most likely you have to use 'end' event to determine, that data fetching is finished.

Very sample code:

```
let data = ""

response.on('data', x => data += x)
response.on('end', () => firesomeCallback(data));
```

Comment: idea is okay, but its not getting inside connection.on('end', ''). Actually am getting data continuously(not fully at a time but one by one) for some minutes and after that its calling/waiting for telnet response giving "ping ......"